# FileReader upload safety

Tags: javascript, security, filereader

Say I have `<input type="file">` without any forms, and obtain an image selected by this `input` via `File`’s `Blob` javascript API:

```
input.addEventListener('change',  function(){

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]); 
reader.onloadend = function() {
var base64data = reader.result;   
               
var i = new Image(); 
i.src = base64data;
i.onload = function(){

var source = imageToDataUri(i,i.width,i.height,0.5);

});
```

And that’s all. Say, there is no php script in my server at all. User just uploads picture via the code below, and, for example, see how the picture is displaying in the web page.

In this case, is the picture actually stored somewhere in my server, and, if yes, can somebody fill all space in the server by just selecting picture in `input`?

---

Probably, I do not understand the blob technology correctly. As far as I understand, if I remove the `onchange` code above, just lefting `input` markup, obviously by selecting file by user, nothing will be send to sever (or already will?). At which line of the code below, browser sends any kind of requests to my server, and what is that request?

Comment: What does it mean for someone to "continuously upload images as blobs **without** actually saving it in your server"? You send an HTTP request to your server. You can send that HTTP from Javascript (as you do), or via any other tool that can send HTTP requests. The server receives identical HTTP requests in the end. It then does something with those requests. What the server does with those requests only your server decides. The one sending the HTTP request cannot dictate what your server does with them, they can only decide the contents of the HTTP request.

Comment: "Blob technology" is all pretty irrelevant here. This is all just happening in the browser on the user's computer. Your server only gets involved when you send this blob via an AJAX request to your server explicitly. At which point, again, it's just an HTTP request, which you could send via any number of tools besides your Javascript as well. What your server does with that request is then up to it. If it stores any and all files sent to it via HTTP, then yes, somebody may be able to "fill it up" by sending it lots of files over HTTP.

Comment: @deceze that is what I actually asking, and in your first comment You gave diametrically opposite answer, although the first, unedited variant of my question was by-sense the same: I emphasized, that I do not sending anything via php, any Ajax and etc, and You wrote: “Your code is sending http request”‍♂️

Comment: Your original question stated *"after that, I am sending an image as base64 string via post request, where, in php script [..]"*, which, for some reason or another, gives the impression you're **uploading those images to your server.** If that's not what you meant, perhaps it wasn't *clear enough.*

Comment: @deceze The original question: “What I am asking is, can that *(mentioned in the question)* javascript code somehow abuse my server? For example, if someone will continuously upload images as blobs **without** actually saving it in my server by sending post request?“. I *clarified* that I am asking about the case, when the users doesn’t use forms, php, ajax or anything else. I just do not understand Your motivation of instantly closing the question that potentially may help someone, especially if it was clarified-enough.

Comment: Your use of the word *"upload"* is problematic here. Using `FileReader` is not *uploading* anything. "Uploading" *means* sending an HTTP request…

Comment: @deceze I using some terminology wrong, I agree, and that’s why I am asking to understand how the things work

Comment: So you see why your question might have been *unclear*…

Comment: @deceze, not unclear enough to instantly close it, as for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing will be uploaded to your server by the `FileReader` nor `Image` API. It's all happening in the browser on the visitor's computer. Only explicit HTTP requests via `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` will cause actual HTTP requests to be sent to your server.

Comment: Thanks, I better change the title of question to `FileReader upload safety`, if, as You write, blob is irrelevant here.